# Print first name, last name in sequence using two threads in java

Tags: java, multithreading, arraylist

I have two `static ArrayList` which contain first name and last name respectively. How to read and print in sequence first name + last name using two threads?

Comment: School assignment?

Comment: This is a new twist on one of the worst multi-threading assignments ever.  You'll learn something about _how_ to make threads do things if you complete it, but it's an absolutely wrong example of _why_ to use threads.  If you want a program to do a sequence of things in a particular order, then the only right way to do it is to do those things _in one thread_.  Asking how to make threads take turns like that is as dumb as asking how to get your airplane through the toll booths when you're driving it on the turnpike.  There's a better use for airplanes, and there's a better use for threads.

Comment: P.S.: My solution to this problem, once I bit the bullet and decided to actually code it for myself, was to pass a token from thread to thread using `BlockingQueue`s.  It generalizes to any number of threads.  Each thread waits to receive the token, does its thing, passes the token on to the next thread, and then goes back to the waiting step.  Or, you could use `Semaphore` objects, and pass a _virtual_ token---slightly less intuitive, but it works just as well.

Answer (score 2):

Since you cannot be certain which thread will run in what order, you can't be sure eg. the first thread running 3 clicks and printing 3 first names without any last names getting printed.

If you somehow make threads run once each turn (like thread 1 prints 1 name then waits for thread 2 to print a last name) then they essentially become 1 thread in practice, so there will be no point in having two threads.

anyways I think one could make a synchronized method that returns name + surname, and increases a counter to remember what position it was on the arrays:

```
class TheClass {
    int i = -1;

    synchronized String getNameSurmame() {
        i++;
        return arraylist1.get(i) + " " + arraylist2.get(i);
    }

    //create two threads that call above method and print...
}
```

ps: Smells like a bad homework assignment. Why do teachers ask students to do bad stuff?

Comment: "Those who can't do, teach". This is not the first time I see similar tasks which essence is how to make several threads work as if they were a single thread.

Comment: +1 Alexei, it's a shame it's like that.... There should be ways to make the threads work in sync... no?  I believe Java 8 has a few classes linked to "Promises" so you could possibly get a promise of the 2 parts.  Also, you could just use 1 thread per list, then do list1[0] + list2[0] but yeah, this assignment..........